# How to test application against Zookeeper

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have an application that uses the Curator framework to determine leadership. We wanted to be able to test state changes from the Zookeeper server, is there a way to do this?

From our perspective, it would be beneficial if we could make the server send connection states to connected clients (CONNECTED, RECONNECTED, SUSPENDED, LOST). I know Curator provides a TestingServer class, but it does not seem to have this functionality.

Any solutions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at Curator's own tests? Many of the tests simulate these events.

Comment: Cool, didn't realize those existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://apache.googlesource.com/curator/+/refs/heads/CURATOR-190/curator-recipes/src/test/java/org/apache/curator/framework/client/TestBackgroundStates.java

```
@Test
public void testConnectionStateListener() throws Exception
{
    server.close();
    Timing timing = new Timing();
    CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(server.getConnectString(), timing.session(), timing.connection(), new RetryOneTime(timing.milliseconds()));
    try
    {
        client.start();
        final BlockingQueue<ConnectionState> stateVector = Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue(1);
        ConnectionStateListener listener = new ConnectionStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(CuratorFramework client, ConnectionState newState)
            {
                stateVector.offer(newState);
            }
        };
        Timing waitingTiming = timing.forWaiting();
        client.getConnectionStateListenable().addListener(listener);
        server = new TestingServer(server.getPort());
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.CONNECTED);
        server.stop();
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.SUSPENDED);
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.LOST);
        server.restart();
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.RECONNECTED);
        server.close();
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.SUSPENDED);
        Assert.assertEquals(stateVector.poll(waitingTiming.milliseconds(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), ConnectionState.LOST);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(client);
    }
}
```